# Golang cast custom type and assign its pointer to a viable

Tags: pointers, go, casting

```
type IntHeap []int
stones := []int{1,2,3}

func main(){
    s := IntHeap(stones) 
    h := &s                //no compile error

    j := &IntHeap(stones)  //compile error
}
```

As shown above, `h := &IntHeap(stones)` cause `compile error`.

Do I have to assign twice in the above example?

I don't like assign to `s` and `assign &s to h`

Can anyone help?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the address

```
j := (*IntHeap)(&stones)
```